# Garage outlet causes unrelated outlet's breaker to trip

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, 240v

When I use the power outlet (240v, 15A) outlet in my garage, it trips the breaker for the power in my home office upstairs. What is also interesting and concerning is that the breaker for the garage power does not trip in this situation.

I've noticed this only happens when a fair bit of current is being drawn from the outlet; e.g. using a corded drill on a tough material. The garage and office outlets are the plain standard type, not GFCI or anything. I should also note that the garage outlet is loose...

So what exactly is happening? How does a dodgy outlet cause another outlet's breaker to trip and not its own?

Comment: Can you upload a picture of the panel showing the breakers for the relevant circuits? What are you using on the 220V circuit? I'll bet you've got an AFCI on the bedroom circuit being tripped by a motor load on the next circuit.

Comment: "Loose" how?  What matters to the electrons is whether the wires are firmly connected and whether any grounding connections (e.g. metal outlet box) are solid.  And like mana..... commented, try disconnecting the AFCI or GFCI in your home office feed and see if that stops the breaker from popping.  Don't disconnect permanently, just to help isolate the problem.

Comment: Yes, I'd be keenly interested to know the labeling on your home office's breaker...

Comment: Yes, can you post photos of the breakers in question please, as well as the panel as a whole?

Comment: Labels are frequently wrong.  If your breaker trips due to load in the garage, then the breaker tripping is for the garage.

Comment: @garageman490, did you ever resolve this issue? I'm having the same symptoms.